# Use react bootstrap table next in class

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Maybe this is a weird question but for newbie its sucks.

I am using the react-bootstrap table next in class and how can I use the function.

let me show u some code.

Here is my class=>

```
export default class TimeDetailByDate extends React.Component{   
      constructor(props){
        super(props);           

        this.state = {
              timesheets : [], 
...
//use this table in render
 <BootstrapTable keyField={"id"} data={this.state.timesheetstemp} columns={columns}>


                  </BootstrapTable>
```

Here is the columns (outside of class)

```
const columns = [  
  {
    dataField: 'tdate',
    text: 'Date',    
    classes : 'p-1',
    formatter : GetDateFormat,
    headerStyle : {
      width:'120px'
    },
    sort : true
  },
  {......
```

In one of the `columnformatter`, I used this function (outside of class)=>

```
function GetActionFormat(cell,row){
  return(<div>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm ts-buttom" size="sm" onClick={this.handleModelEdit(row)}>Edit</button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm ml-2 ts-buttom" size="sm">Delete</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Problem is here, this handleModelEdit is inside of class and when call like that it happen error

> TypeError: this.handleModelEdit is not a function

this function needs some data from the class constructor field. So how can I use that?

Hope u will understand my question and Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if I got the question right, but it seems to me that you haven't bind the handleModelEdit function in the constructor. Try this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    ...

    this.handleModelEdit = this.handleModelEdit.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure what the problem is. Could you please provide an example in [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) ?